# What's the right way to add product flavors in react native?

Tags: android, react-native, fastlane, android-productflavors

After i added product flavors in my react native project, the app always crashes when i made a release, right after i started it.

I tried to open android studio to see Logcat, but since the app crashes in the moment it's started i couldn't see anything.

Here is part of my app/build.gladle:

```
project.ext.envConfigFiles = [
    dev: ".env.local",
    production: ".env.production",
    staging: ".env.staging"
]

apply from: project(':react-native-config').projectDir.getPath() + "/dotenv.gradle"

android {
    flavorDimensions "default"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.company"
        applicationIdSuffix ""
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
        resValue "string", "build_config_package", "com.company"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), 
            "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        dev {
            minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
            targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
            applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
            versionNameSuffix "-dev"
        }
        staging {
            minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
            targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
            applicationIdSuffix ".staging"
            versionNameSuffix "-staging"
        }
        production {
        }
    }
}
```

I'm also using fastLane for deploy my app, like this:

```
lane :staging do |options|
gradle(task: 'clean')
gradle(
  task: "assemble",
  flavor: "Staging",
  build_type: "Release",
  print_command: false,
  properties: {
    "android.injected.signing.store.file" => "file.keystore",
    "android.injected.signing.store.password" => options[:storepass],
    "android.injected.signing.key.alias" => options[:keyalias],
    "android.injected.signing.key.password" => options[:keypass],
  }
)
upload_to_play_store(track: 'alpha')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename your productFlavors, for example:

Change `dev` to `devTest`.